# 2 products next to each other on Woocommerce product category page

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I use the Wordpress Avada-theme and Woocommerce for a webshop. Now I have put some code in my css to display 2 products next to each other in my shop in Avada in responsive view.

I used this code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
/* lists on mobile */
div.woocommerce.columns-4 > ul {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: flex-start;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
/*li elements on mobile*/
div.woocommerce.columns-4 > ul > li {
width: 50%;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
}
```

Now on the homepage ([Aalvink.nl](https://aalvink.nl)`) I get 2 products next to each other (big improvement), but on the product-category pages the I still see 1 product per column (eg https://www.aalvink.nl/product-categorie/bbq-american-style/).

Does anybody know how to fix this? Or can anyone see what I've done wrong that these category-pages are being excluded from this styling?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  /* lists on mobile */
    .products.products-4 {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: flex-start;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
  /*li elements on mobile*/
    .products.products-4 > li {
      width: 50%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
  }
```

You dont have div with 'woocommerce columns-4' classes on page https://www.aalvink.nl/product-categorie/bbq-american-style/

Answer (score 0):

In home page, there is a width of 49% while it is different in product page. I have added the CSS in my answer with media query as it is needed only in mobile view. Hope this helps.

```css
@media (max-width:767px){
  #main ul.products > li.product{
      width:49%;
      float:left !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code of the page, you have forgotten to wrap your UL element with your div.woocommerce.columns-4

If you wrap your UL element in the product page, you should get the same result.